# cookies are not being sent during post request (flask-cors)

Tags: flask, cookies, flask-cors

i have credentials in cookies that must be sent over a post request, but they are not present.

however, they are present in get requests

here is my flask cors config

```
CORS(
    app,
    resources={"/*": {"origins": ["http://localhost:3000", "http://localhost:1002"]}},
    allow_headers="*",
    supports_credentials=True,
    expose_headers=[
        "tokens",
        "Set-Cookie",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials",
    ],
)
```

here is the response from preflight (options)
[image]

As you can tell I have allow credentials true, and my allow-origin is explicitly set to an origin

again, all get requests succeed, while all post requests fail with a 401 where the cookies are nowhere to be found.

Comment: How is the client sending the request? For instance, if you're using `fetch`, are you specifying `credentials: 'include'` in the options?

Comment: Side note: listing `Set-Cookie` as an exposed header is pointless, because browsers never grant the client access to that response header. Not too sure why you're exposing `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`, as those response headers are only useful for the CORS protocole.